# I want to update a calendar with holidays in a separate db

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using C#.net and MVC + razor engine.

I want to update a calendar. The holidays are saved in a separate table in SQL. I need to get that data and update the calendar so that the users will be able to see the holidays in a different color.

Can I do with a jquery?

Comment: http://www.techtricky.com/jquery-datepicker-how-to-mark-the-holidays-on-calendar/

Comment: Thanks Temaska.....
I got some ideas from that. thanks..... actually I need to get the holidays from a table not from hardcoded values :)
any idea??? :)